# VMware内部エラー発生時の復旧方法について

Tags: windows, vmware

Windows10 64bitのPCでVMware Workstation 12 Playerを利用中です。
現在以下内容のエラーが発生しており、起動ができない状態です。

> ディスク (仮想マシン名).vmdk には 1 つ以上の修正不可能な内部エラーがあります。このディスクのバックアップ
>   コピーからリストアしてください。 指定された仮想ディスクを修復する必要があります
>   ディスク「(仮想マシン名).vmdk」、またはこのディスクが依存するスナップショット ディスクを開くことができません。 モジュール Disk
>   のパワーオンに失敗しました。

使用OSはUbuntu16.04です。
この2週間程で2～3回発生しており、原因もわかっておりません。
発生する原因、また、復旧方法があれば教えていただきたいです。宜しくお願い致します。